# Don't know how to implement range to amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

i'm using the amcharts plugin to create nice charts. I found a couple of things to add ranges but the structure of the chart code is different then mine and i can't seem to find out how to implement it with my code. here is how i set up my graph.

```js
var chartConfig = {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "none",
  "marginLeft": 70,
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "graphs": [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bulletSize": 5,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "title": "red line",
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
    "valueField": "value"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    "labelsEnabled": false,
    "tickLength": 0
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true
  }],

var charts = [];
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", chartConfig));
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", chartConfig2));
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv3", chartConfig3));

for (var x in charts) {
  charts[x].addListener("zoomed", syncZoom);
  charts[x].addListener("init", addCursorListeners);
}

function addCursorListeners(event) {
  event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("changed", handleCursorChange);
  event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("onHideCursor", handleHideCursor);
}

function syncZoom(event) {
  for (x in charts) {
    if (charts[x].ignoreZoom) {
      charts[x].ignoreZoom = false;
    }
    if (event.chart != charts[x]) {
      charts[x].ignoreZoom = true;
      charts[x].zoomToDates(event.startDate, event.endDate);
    }
  }
}

function handleCursorChange(event) {
  for (var x in charts) {
    if (event.chart != charts[x]) {
      charts[x].chartCursor.syncWithCursor(event.chart.chartCursor);
    }
  }
}

function handleHideCursor() {
  for (var x in charts) {
    if (charts[x].chartCursor.hideCursor) {
      charts[x].chartCursor.forceShow = false;
      charts[x].chartCursor.hideCursor(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Does somebody know how to implement the range in my case? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share a complete example please? There are some parts missing in your code.

Comment: Maybe its better to edit your question, instead using comments.

Comment: Since you're using v3, you are likely referring to *guides* like colored area with the "fines" text in [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/stacked-area-v3/). Axis ranges are in v4. Is the guide example what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on v3, I'm assuming you're referring to [***guides***](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide). [Axis ranges](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/) are a v4 feature that can accomplish the same thing.

Guides can be added to the chart object by specifying a start/end point, fill, line color and optional text. If you're drawing a guide on the category axis, either use `date`/`toDate` or `category`/`toCategory`. If you're drawing a guide on a value axis, use `value`/`toValue`:

```
guides: [{
  //date-based category axis guide
  date: "2019-02-20", 
  toDate: "2019-02-22",
  fillAlpha: .20,
  fillColor: "#ee7d01",
  label: "Category Axis guide",
  inside: true //move label inside instead of displaying it on the axis
}, {
  //value axis guide
  value: 10,
  toValue: 30,
  fillAlpha: .20,
  fillColor: "#10d7ee",
  label: "Value Axis guide",
  inside: false //keep label outside along the axis
}]
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/aff637c76d7a18ee95b8e9ce57d0a480?editors=0010)

Comment: is it possible to dynamically change the value and tovalue like this : function changeTresh(){
    var treshhold1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("treshhold1").value);
    var treshhold2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("treshhold2").value);
    
    console.log(treshhold1);
    console.log(treshhold2);
    if(treshhold1 & treshhold2 != 0){
    chartConfig.guides["0"].value = treshhold1;
    chartConfig.guides["0"].toValue = treshhold2;
    
        
    chartConfig.guides["1"].toValue= treshhold1;
    
    chartConfig.guides["2"].value = treshhold2;
    
    }
}

Comment: <input type="button" value="Change treshholds" id="btChangeTresh" onclick="changeTresh()"> this is my button. the code seems fine tome but maybe it's just not possible to do it like that

Comment: @Tilou - you could have at the very least accepted this answer before opening a separate question for this followup.